# Ordenar LinkedList de manera aleatoria java

Tags: java

Tengo una LinkedList de 104 elementos y necesito ordenarlos de manera aleatoria en java.

Es un estilo de mazo de cartas y hay que barajar antes de comenzar a jugar.
yo intenté

```
for(int i =0;i<104;i++){
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 103) + 1;
            String q=mazo.get(rand);
            mazo.set(rand,mazo.get(i));
            mazo.set(rand,q);
        }
```

Comment: no ordena? cual es el error? cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: no, no ordena, imprimo la lista y me la entrega exactamente igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-), el cual:

> Cambia aleatoriamente la lista especificada utilizando una fuente
>   predeterminada de aleatoriedad. Todas las permutaciones ocurren con
>   aproximadamente la misma probabilidad.

### Código:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO EN REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/SDNA52245)</kbd>

Creamos una lista con 10 elementos y luego hacemos que `Collections.shuffle` la ordene dos veces. Podrás ver que cada orden es distinto del original, y distingo entre sí:

```
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    list.add("Elemento-01");
    list.add("Elemento-02");
    list.add("Elemento-03");
    list.add("Elemento-04");
    list.add("Elemento-05");
    list.add("Elemento-06");
    list.add("Elemento-07");
    list.add("Elemento-08");
    list.add("Elemento-09");
    list.add("Elemento-10");

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println("1ª prueba:");
    for(String str: list){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println("\n2ª prueba:");
    for(String str: list){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

**Salida:**

```
1ª prueba:
Elemento-07
Elemento-02
Elemento-06
Elemento-08
Elemento-01
Elemento-10
Elemento-05
Elemento-03
Elemento-09
Elemento-04

2ª prueba:
Elemento-04
Elemento-06
Elemento-01
Elemento-08
Elemento-09
Elemento-07
Elemento-10
Elemento-02
Elemento-05
Elemento-03
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @StivensonSarrazola Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.